Using Custom User Defined Constraints on Moveit2 for Planning Scene
I am trying to use custom constraints to move my arm. I want the arm to focus at a target point in space while moving from A to B. This target, including the start and goal are sent from a custom service call to Moveit2. The custom constraint I am using was here.
However the robot does not adhere the constraint and the camera just look forwards without facing the target. The FOV of the camera_sensor is facing the +Y direction.
class TrajectoryPlanner
{
public:
TrajectoryPlanner(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr node, const std::string& name, const std::string& group_name, const std::string& planning_service)
: group_name_(group_name) // Now matches the declaration order
, node_(node)
, planning_service_(planning_service)
, move_group_(node, group_name_)
{
setupPlanningScene();
moveit_service = node_->create_service<custom_robot_msgs::srv::SetPlan>(
planning_service_,
std::bind(&TrajectoryPlanner::handleTrajectory, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));

RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "TrajectoryPlanner service ready");
}

private:
void handleTrajectory(const std::shared_ptr<custom_robot_msgs::srv::SetPlan::Request> request,
std::shared_ptr<custom_robot_msgs::srv::SetPlan::Response> response)
{
RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), “Received plan trajectory request”);
handleScalingFactors(request->velocity_scaling, request->acceleration_scaling);
setLookAtParams(request->look_at_enabled, request->face_target);

if (request->is_pose)
{
  if (!planAndExecute(request->target_pose))
  {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(node_->get_logger(), "Failed to execute Target Pose !! Aborting.");
    response->success = false;
    return;
  }
}
else
{
  if (!planAndExecute(request->target_joints))
  {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(node_->get_logger(), "Failed to reach Target Joint Position !! Aborting.");
    response->success = false;
    return;
  }
}

RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "Execution towards the target succeeded");
response->success = true;
}

bool lookAtConstraint(const moveit::core::RobotState& state, bool verbose)
{
const Eigen::Isometry3d& end_effector_pose = state.getGlobalLinkTransform(“camera_sensor_link”);
Eigen::Vector3d end_effector_direction = end_effector_pose.rotation() * Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY();

Eigen::Vector3d target_position(face_target[0], face_target[1], face_target[2]);
Eigen::Vector3d to_target = (target_position - end_effector_pose.translation()).normalized();

double angle = std::acos(end_effector_direction.dot(to_target));
return angle <= 0.1;
}

void setupPlanningScene()
{
robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader(node_, “robot_description”);
const moveit::core::RobotModelPtr& kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
planning_scene = std::make_shared<planning_scene::PlanningScene>(kinematic_model);
// Update the lambda to take both the state and the verbose parameter
planning_scene->setStateFeasibilityPredicate([this](const moveit::core::RobotState& state, bool verbose) → bool {
return lookAtConstraint(state, verbose);
});
}

